# jquery editable extra button/link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery's editable and with submit and cancel I also want to 1 extra button for other functionality... can anyone help?

Comment: what function u want with another button??

Comment: I will be calling a popup with the link/button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to extend the plugin... do the following changes in the source

```
onEdit: null,
            onSubmit: null,
            onPopup: null, //function to be called when you click your custom popup button
            onCancel: null,
            editClass: null,
            submit: null,
            popup: null, //your custom popup button
            popupBy: 'blur', //blur, change, dbclick, click
            cancel: null,
            type: 'text',
```

after  that you'll have to define the options like

```
// popup event 
            if (opts.popup) {
                $('<button/>').appendTo($this)
                        .html(opts.popup)
                        .one('mouseup', function () { opts.toNonEditable($(this).parent(), true) });
            } else
                $this.one(opts.popupBy, function () { opts.toNonEditable($(this), true) })
                 .children()
                    .one(opts.popupBy, function () { opts.toNonEditable($(this).parent(), true) });
```

finally add the following to the source to call user defined functions

```
 // Call User Function
            var func = null;
            if ($.isFunction(opts.onSubmit) && change == true)
                func = opts.onSubmit;
            else if ($.isFunction(opts.onCancel) && change == false)
                func = opts.onCancel;
            else if ($.isFunction(opts.onPopup) && change == true)
                func = opts.onPopup;
```

if everything go fine you can use it as

```
$('selector').editable({
    type: 'select',
    options: { 'value1': 'Item 1', 2: 'Item 2', 'Item 3': 'Item 3' },
    submit: 'save',
    popup:'click to open popup',
    cancel: 'cancel',
    editClass: 'colored',
    onEdit: editFuncion,
    onPopup:popupFunction,
    onSubmit: submitFuncion
});

function popupFunction() { 

// your logic to open popup

}
```

**Disclaimer**

i have not tested it so i cannot confirm whether it'll work or not but you'll get the idea